# Resize image based on vertical seekbar?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, seekbar

I am trying to measure a user height by moving a vertical seekbar. The issue is that when i try to resize an image, the image in some screens appears larger then the seekbar thumbnail, or lower than the thumbnail. How can I solve this problem. The code I wrote:

```
 verticalSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                int measure = (int) ((((float) progress * point.x) / 250) - (progress * 0.5)) - 250;

                if (progress > 140) {
                    if (point.x - measure < personImage.getHeight()) {
                        params.height = point.x - personImage.getHeight();
                    } else {
                        params.height = measure;
                    }


                    // Set LayoutParams
                    personImage.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

This is the result I want to archive:

[image]

Comment: `height = verticalSeekBar.height * (verticalSeekBar.progress/100)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If case that your seekbar max value != 100, than probably this is going to solve your issue:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
verticalSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {

        params.height = (int) (verticalSeekBar.getHeight() * (float) progress / YOUR_MAX_VALUE) + (int)((YOUR_MAX_VALUE - progress) / 2);
        personImage.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Was trying to edit @shkschneider answer, but this solved my problem completely.